# DOMDocument: the root element gets just a single tag, not both

Tags: php, xml, root

the following code should create an XML file using DOMDocument with a   root element:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $doc->formatOutput = true;

        $root = $doc->createElement('gallery');
        $doc->appendChild($root);

        $doc->save($filename);
```

but I just get a single tag element  (with that slash "/"), instead of

`<gallery> </gallery>`

I managed to get

```
<gallery> A content </gallery>
```

if I use createElement with the second parameter ( $doc->createElement('gallery', 'A content') ) but since it's the root element, I don't need to put a content in there.

How to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`<gallery />` is equivalent to `<gallery></gallery>`. If you were to add content to the "single tag element", it would be rendered with the start and end tags, and the content between.

Comment: The mysterious world of XML. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`<gallery/>` is the short serialization form for an empty tag. If loaded into an DOM it will result in the same node. So most of the time it is just irrelevant and you can use the short empty form.

However, you can require DOM to save empty tags in the long form:

```
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$document->formatOutput = true;

$root = $document->appendChild(
  $document->createElement('gallery')
);

// echo $document->save($filename, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
echo $document->saveXml(null, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gallery></gallery>
```